# Find out the Creator of Site in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How to find out the Creator/DateTime Created of a site in sharepoint 2007.

I am assuming can I check thru the content database or anywhere in the properties, not through object modelling code.

Thank you.
Hari

Comment: I'm assuming you wish to know this via code, correct?

Comment: Not thru the object modelling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. He would be in the Owners group but there could be more people in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Site Creator, Created Time, etc by accessing the SPWeb.Author, SPWeb.Created properties.

Here is an Application page to Get List Owners: [Custom Application Page to get List Owners](http://salaudeen.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-create-custom-application-page.html)